# webapp2 route fails

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, webapp2

I'm building my new website using app-engine with python and webapp2
I'm having hard times to define the URIs in my web application

the result I need is:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/products/
http://www.example.com/products/table
```

I thought it's an easy task, but apparently it is not (for me, anyway)

I'm getting 404 error when I'm trying to load something like that:
http://www.example.com/products/chair/

where is my mistake?

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
webapp2.Route('/', MainPage),
webapp2.Route('/products/', handler=MainProductsHandler),
webapp2.Route('/products/(\w+)/', handler=ProductHandler)
],debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure your URLs are getting to your webapp file at all? What does your `app.yaml` look like?

Comment: application: myappengineapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

builtins:
- remote_api: on

handlers:

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
  
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved it.
just like that:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/product/.*', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I think that I had a problem when I used the webapp2.Route method

thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach would work using angle brackets wrapping the regular expresion like this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
webapp2.Route('/', MainPage),
webapp2.Route('/products/', handler=MainProductsHandler),
webapp2.Route('/products/<id:(\w+)>/', handler=ProductHandler)
],debug=True)
```

Don't forget to add the param id (or whatever name your choose for the regex match) to the handler's get method else it will complain about an unexpected param.